# react, react-redux delay on state update. How to handle?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, state, transition

Using reactjs with redux and react-router, redux-thunk  I have a problem with state update.

Having some routes where I show single post and calling from this page another post I have a delay where the old state is getting shown till the new state updates.

I have the post reducer

```
import * as types from '../actions/actionTypes';
import initialState from './initialState';

export default function sessionReducer(state = initialState.post, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case types.POST_SUCCESS:
            return action.post
        case types.ERROR:
            return null;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

and here my actions

```
import * as types from './actionTypes';
import axios from 'axios';

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    var postEndPoint = 'http://dev.test.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?slug=';
} else {
    var postEndPoint = 'http://prod.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?slug=';
}

export function getPost (slug) {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(setLoadingState()); // Show a loading spinner

        axios.all([
            axios.get(postEndPoint + slug)
        ]).then(axios.spread(function ( post) {
                dispatch(setPost(post.data))
                dispatch(doneFetchingData(post.data))

            }))
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
                dispatch(showError(error))
            });
    }
}

function setPost(post) {
    return {
        type: types.POST_SUCCESS,
        post: post
    }
}

function setLoadingState() {
    return {
        type: types.SHOW_SPINNER,
        loaded: false
    }
}

function doneFetchingData( post) {
    return {
        type: types.HIDE_SPINNER,
        loaded: true,
        post: post
    }
}

function showError(error) {
    console.log(error)
    return {
        type: types.SHOW_ERROR,
        loaded: false,
        error: error
    }
}
```

How do I deal with this problem or what I made wrong?

Comment: When fetching a post with `getPost`, dispatch a `null` or `undefined` as current post, for example `dispatch(setPost(null))`, so you don't render old post data while loading.

Comment: yepp thanks I made it between and it works